# How to organize a large array used by a function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a large array of URLs, up to 500 URLs. I have a function in my helper class, `Helpers.php`, and I loop through this array and perform actions on each URL within the array.

Currently, I have the array within the function, but this seems really messy to me, like:

```
function getURLData() {
    $urls = array( ... 500 URL array ... )
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        // Perform actions on $url
    }
}
```

However, the function looks incredibly cluttered with all 500 URLs being listed there. How can I reorganize this to make the function more readable? Should I store the array in a separate file? How? Where?

P.S. I am using Laravel 5.2.

Comment: I think this question belongs to Code review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Keep them and all similar data in a database. That's what DB for - keeping large amount of similar structured data. Hardcoding any kind of data in the code is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hardcode those URLs, I suggest you to create a new folder called "Enum" for you enumerations, and a class like UrlEnum. You can make something like:

```
class UrlEnum {
    const URLS = ['http://...','https://...', ...];
}
```

PHP version older than 5.6 doesn't accept array in const, so you can use private/protected variable, and some public static getUrls().

And do `foreach(UrlEnum::URLS as $url) { ... }`.

If you like this approach, you can even create a BaseEnum, or AbstractEnum so all of your enums will implement/have the same functions.